# show child li when it's container ul is applied display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using sortable plugin of Jquery UI and playing with the example that it came with named "connect-lists.html". I want to hide the first ul by using `display:none` (not `visibility:hidden`!!) but let the `li` being dragged show on screen. This is the code of the demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="../../jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../demos.css">
    <style>
    #sortable1, #sortable2 
    { 
         list-style-type: none;  
         margin: 0;  
         padding: 0 0 2.5em;  
         float: left;  
         margin-right: 10px;  
    }
    #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li 
    { 
         margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;  
         padding: 5px;  
         font-size: 1.2em;  
         width: 120px;  
         overflow:visible;display:block;  
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
            start: function(event, ui){
                $('#sortable1').hide();
                //is it possible to show the ui.item???
            },
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        }).disableSelection();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="demo">

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>

</div><!-- End demo -->



<div class="demo-description">
<p>
    Sort items from one list into another and vice versa, by passing a selector
    into the <code>connectWith</code> option. The simplest way to do this is to
    group all related lists with a CSS class, and then pass that class into the
    sortable function (i.e., <code>connectWith: '.myclass'</code>).
</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->

</body>
</html>
```

I've just added an start event and I hide the `ul` there. Problem here is when I start dragging the item from 1st list onto 2nd, both the ul and the li gets disappeared. How do I get around this issue?

Comment: If you hide a ul, its children will all be hidden. I would suggest hiding the individual li items instead of the whole ul.

Comment: Instead of hiding all of the 10's of li's that might be present in my real project, is it possible to explicitly show the li that is being dragged?

Comment: Yes, of course. I didn't mean hide them each individually. Hide them all, then show as needed, or visa versa, whichever is easier for you.

Comment: Sorry, I checked it with my project's html and it's not possible :(. My real project has a outer div. The UL is inside div and I want to hide the div. I can't hide any other element.

Comment: I don't know how well it would work, but you could pull your li out of the div entirely, ($.detach() I think).

Comment: @Torr3nt: Even me not sure how sortable would behave if I detach it :) but it is worth giving a try.